# Is 'begun' a better translation than 'made' in John 1:3?

Tags: greek, john

> παντα δι αυτου εγενετο και χωρις αυτου εγενετο ουδε εν ο γεγονεν [TR] John1:3
>
> All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made. [KJV]
>
> All things through him did happen, and without him happened not even one thing that hath happened. [YLT]
>
> All things through him came into being, and without him came into being not even one [thing] which has come into being. [EGNT]

Since the context in these first few verses is 'in the beginning' (εν αρχη) in both verse one and verse two, I wondered if a better translation would be one which agrees with both the EGNT (The Englishman's Greek New Testament) and Young's Literal :

> All things were begun through (δι) him and without him was not anything begun that was begun.

The KJV states 'made' three times but the verb is not ποιεο, 'do or make', but γινομαι, 'to become, to come to pass, to arise' [Thayer].

Is 'begun' a better expression of γινομαι than 'made' ?

Comment: Your question at the top asks for the better of two translations. The question at the bottom asks for the better of two expressions, which requests an opinion. Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: @JohnMartin I asked is one a 'better expression of γινομαι' than another. That is to say, a better expression (in English) of the concept. The concept is common to both languages. What is sought is the better expression of that concept in language. It is not an opinion, it is a matter of scientific study, the knowledge of languages.

Comment: If you disagree, can you not use the word "translation" twice? You seem to have 2 questions.

Comment: @JohnMartin   'Expression : _4a Manner or means of representation in language; wording, diction, phraseology_ [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/66747?redirectedFrom=expression#eid). 'Means of representation' is exactly my meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is not. The actual translation of "γεγονεν" is happened. So Everything happened through him and without him nothing would have happened from the ones that happened. Is a better translation. However, bare in mind that in greek, one word has at least 3 meanings, which are all valid! for the meaning the write wants to pass. For example, on your other section of the question,'in the beginning' (εν αρχη) , "εν αρχη" means, in the beggining, but at the same time, it also mean, "in power", the one who commands the leader. A passage that origins back to the students of Pythagoreas, using the exact same words bar the word god which was replaced with the work harmony.
Sorry I can't site on that, as I would have to use an ancient greek passage claimed to be written by pythagorean students.

Comment: αρχη does not mean power, it means the principle or head of something.

Comment: Some references and links are needed, here. Otherwise, it is just a personal opinion.

Comment: Nigel you are right... here is the comment on "αρχη" also meaning authority, the one who is in power  https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=astynomiki+arxi+in+english . in the same manner, it can be found that the translation of "γεγονεν" = "έγινε" in modern greek, is happened in the strongest of its meanings. That only leaves the part that every ancient greek word would have at least 3 meanings. This is more of an emperical knowledge and a proof of that ,would be to link a leaxicon of ancient greek. I won't do that for apparent reasons